# Count Userid In Last 5 Results

Tags: php

I need to know if the last 5 entry's in a table were placed by the same userid (in the code below the user id is `frozen_by`.

Here's what I have

```
//count if the last 5 freezes was placed by the same user

$strFind="SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `contest_frozen` WHERE `contest_id`=\"$pid\" AND `frozen_by`=\"$curmemid\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$freeze_total=$row['total'];

if($freeze_total>=5){
//do this
}

if($freeze_total<5){
//do this
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I've correctly understand.. Your user id is `frozen_by` which you explicitely defined in `frozen_by=\"$curmemid\"` so in this case there are for sure 5 results with the same user id

Comment: I think, the question have not finished yet.

Comment: `select count(*) from ...` is NEVER going to return more than one row anyways unless you have a group-by clause

Comment: Yes. check your if conditions. they are misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this: It returns the number of different users in the last 5 rows. It also returns the highest userid, so if `UserCount == 1` and `MaxUser == $curmemid` then you know that that user places the last five records.

```
SELECT
  count(distinct frozen_by) as UserCount,
  max(frozen_by) as MaxUser
FROM 
  contest_frozen
WHERE 
  contest_id = $pid 
ORDER BY 
  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

If you need explicit counts, you can do that too. Query below returns the number of records by the given user and the number of records by other users. If ThisUserCount == 5 then all 5 records are from that user.

```
SELECT
  sum(case when frozen_by = $curmemid then 1 else 0 end) as ThisUserCount,
  sum(case when frozen_by = $curmemid then 0 else 1 end) as OtherUserCount

FROM 
  contest_frozen
WHERE 
  contest_id = $pid 
ORDER BY 
  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```